# What dangers are there in creating collections which extend native arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I created a Collection based on this [article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2292-extending-javascript-arrays-while-keeping-native-bracket-notation-functionality.htm). I found that this runs on chrome, firefox and ie9+.
I assume some things are not going to work or maybe, the ie9 emulator for windows 10 just doesn't give me the real picture.

What could go wrong with this extension?

Test code:

```
<script>
    function Collection() {
        var collection = Object.create( Array.prototype );

        collection = (Array.apply( collection, arguments ) || collection);


        return collection;
    }

    Collection.prototype =  Object.create(Array.prototype);

    var collection = new Collection();

    collection[0] = 1;

    console.log(collection[0]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/.

In particular,

> ```
> var collection = Object.create(Array.prototype);
> ```

creates an object that does inherit from `Array.prototype` not `Collection.prototype`. And it creates an *object*, not an array.

> ```
> collection = (Array.apply( collection, arguments ) …
> ```

`Array` ignores its `this` value. And creates an `Array` instance, not a `Collection` one.

> ```
> … || collection)
> ```

This is pointless, as `Array` never returns a falsy value, so `collection` is simply always ignored.

> What could go wrong with this extension?

It creates `Array`s, not `Collection`s. There is no extension at all. Try putting some methods at `Collection.prototype` and invoke them.

Comment: An other big point : `collection.push('hello'); collection.length = 0; collection[0]; // 'hello'`.

Comment: @Kaiido That is when it's an object instead of an array, yes.